# I cannot trigger a random function when a given button is pressed in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a button which will display a message in the tkinter module in Python.

At first, the button has text on it. When it is clicked, it will display a messagebox. A messagebox is a "pop-up" or "error message."

The below code will show a sample function that executes the above sentence.

```
def joke1():
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "There are three types of people in this world", message = "Those who can count and those who can't.")

root = Tk()
root.title("Joke Board 1.0 by Jamlandia")
root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\VMWZh\Downloads\Icons8-Ios7-Messaging-Lol.ico")
button = Button(text = "There are three types of people in this world", bg = '#42f474', fg = 'black', command = joke1)
test = Button()

button.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

test.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
root.mainloop()
```

I can not figure out a way to approach coding it so that when you press the button, it will run the function that correlates with the joke that is displayed on the button, then randomly bind to a new function and the text to change to the joke that correlates with that function.

Comment: please add the rest of the relevant code (the button/messagebox etc)

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question to help. Please provide a [mcve] which illustrates the part of the problem you are struggling with.

Comment: Why do you want to "randomly bind" the button to a new function? Why not have the button call a single function that can display a joke from a list of jokes? What's the value in having more than one function?

Comment: do you mean `button["text"] = "Hello World"` and `button["command"] = function_hello_world`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: press the button, ... randomly ... change to the joke

#### tkinter — Python interface to Tcl/Tk

- [Tk Concepts](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#widgets)
- [Label](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#label)
- [Button](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#button)
- [The Grid Geometry Manager](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html)

#### The Python Tutorial and Python Module

- [9. Classes - 9.5. Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)
- [9.3.5. Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)
- [`random.randrange(start, stop[, step])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-integers)

---

Show **random** `Joke` on `Button` click, without `messagbox`.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.joke_index = 0
        self.jokes = [("There are three types of people in this world", "Those who can count and those who can't."),
                      ('Grew up with six brothers', 'That’s how I learned to dance–waiting for the bathroom'),
                      ('Always borrow money from a pessimist.', 'He won’t expect it back.')
                      ]
       
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=3)
        
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self)
        self.label2.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=3)

        button = tk.Button(self,
                           text='Show next Joke',
                           command=self.show_random_joke,
                           bg='#42f474', fg='black'
                           )
        button.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=3)

    def show_random_joke(self):
        v = -1
        while v == self.joke_index:
            v = random.randrange(0, len(self.jokes)-1)
        self.joke_index = v

        self.label1['text'], self.label2['text'] = self.jokes[self.joke_index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5***